# Filter Pivot table on user input

Tags: vba, excel

I need to filter a pivot table on user input value in input box in Excel. how do  I filter this pivot table on user input value that I take in LYear. Below is my code which doesn't work

```
 Sub LoopThroughPivotItems()

 Dim PT As PivotTable
 Dim PF As PivotField
 Dim PI As PivotItem

Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4")
'Set PF = PT.PivotFields("2013")

LYear = InputBox("Enter Year")
'PF.Value = LYear
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("2012").CurrentPage = LYear

'PF.AutoShowField = LYear

'PF.AutoShowField = "LYear"


'For Each PI In PF.PivotItems
'PI.Visible = True ' Error is occuring here
'Next PI


If PI = PF.PivotItems Then
PI.Visible = True
Else: PI.Visible = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try recording a macro?

Comment: yes but that didnt work   i added this code                                  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("2011").PivotItems(LYear).Visible = True
 But what it does is it does not remove the previous selected value ...meaning if i have 2012 entered it will show me data for 2012 and also 2011 if i have selected them previously.. now i need to refresh them....

Comment: Try clearing the filters using `.ClearAllFilters` before assigning any new value to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lYear = InputBox("Enter Year")
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Year").PivotItems(lYear).Visible = True
For Each pit In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Year").PivotItems
    If pit.Value <> lYear Then
        pit.Visible = False
    End If
Next pit
```

Comment: This assumes the field is called "Year" and that you are selecting years within this